# Convert clojure vector to flambo sql row

Tags: sql, clojure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, flambo

I'm working on developing a function to convert a vector into an sql row to further convert it to a data-frame and save it into table using SQLcontext in Apache spark. I'm developing in clojure and I got lost along the way.
I thought of implementing the solution thus:

1. For each rdd (vector) convert it to rows
2. Convert the rows to a data frame
3. Save data frame to a table
4. use the sqlContext to query for particular information in the table
5. and how to convert the result from query into into RDD again for further analysis.

   ```
   (defn assign-ecom 
     []
      (let [rdd-fields (-> (:rdd @transformed-rdd)
                    (f/map #(sql/row->vec %))
                     f/collect)]
        (clojure.pprint/pprint rdd-fields)))
   ```

I'm using flambo v0.60 api function for abstracting Apache-spark functions, I also welcome any suggestion as to how to go about solving the problem. Thanks

Here's the link to Flambo row -> vec docs:

[Flambo documentation:](http://yieldbot.github.io/flambo/codox/flambo.sql.html#var-row-.3Evec)

Comment: @zero323 Thanks!. I tried editing it but somehow, the code wasn't properly formatted

Comment: If you have a list you need another level of nesting for code (8 spaces in total).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you already have `spark-context` (`sc`) and `sql-context` (`sql-ctx`). First lets import all the stuff we'll need:

```
(import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory)
(import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
(import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField)
(import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata)
(import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes)
```

1. For each rdd (vector) convert it to rows

   ```
   ;; Vector to Row conversion
   (defn vec->row [v] 
     (RowFactory/create (into-array Object v)))

   ;; Example data
   (def rows (-> (f/parallelize sc [["foo" 1] ["bar" 2]])
                 (f/map vec->row)))
   ```
2. Convert the rows to a data frame

   ```
   ;; Define schema
   (def schema
     (StructType.
      (into-array StructField
        [(StructField. "k" (DataTypes/StringType) false (Metadata/empty))
         (StructField. "v" (DataTypes/IntegerType) false (Metadata/empty))])))

   ;; Create data frame
   (def df (.createDataFrame sql-ctx rows schema))

   ;; See if it works
   (.show df)
   ```
3. Save data frame to a table

   ```
   (.registerTempTable df "df")
   ```
4. use the sqlContext to query for particular information in the table

   ```
   (def df-keys (.sql sql-ctx "SELECT UPPER(k) as k FROM df"))
   ;; Check results
   (.show df-keys)
   ```
5. and how to convert the result from query into into RDD again for further analysis.

   ```
   (.toJavaRDD df-keys)
   ```

   or if you want vectors:

   ```
   (f/map (.toJavaRDD df-keys) sql/row->vec)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. This is exactly what I needed